# How navigate to a page in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation, ionic3

How can navigate to a page which have some child, from a parent page when you are in it's child?
since i try to do my url goes wrong. I guess child of previous page don't change and just parent of them change. If i'm right how can remove child of last parent.
Can anyone describe navigation system in ionic, i did not find any proper guide in ionic docs for advance navigation.

Comment: You should read the doc about  [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) and if you need more help, you should provide your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the personnel of the Angular has in its documentation examples of routes and even of routes daughters, already I a look?

this link has examples of implementation.
[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/magqlprjprj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

[enter link description here](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5)